# foobar2000 with Google Music?

Tags: foobar2000, google-music

Is there way to connect foobar2000 to Google Music? I was looking for some add-on but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/foobar2000-google-music/source/checkout ?

Comment: have you? :) Whatever it does it seems to be relying on PHP.

Comment: I don't use Google Music, but that appears to be a way to do it with Foobar2k.

Comment: Except that when you check the source files you can see that it is just a bunch of PHP-scripts calling foobar2k via cmdline. :(

Comment: I've been wanting this for ages!  I'm at the point where I'm about to just start coding...

Comment: Since the above isn't a solution for you and there appears to not be anything else, I suppose the only way to get this is to write something using the SDK.

Comment: I think it's better question how to connect to google.music from countries which in list of banned countries?;))

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi \*cough\*VPN\*cough\*

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of searching led me to this.

http://code.google.com/p/foobar2000-google-music/

> You can use this to enjoy google music with foobar2000 in China.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Music Manager](https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#manager) to download your Library. Then add the folder where you downloaded your Library to Foobar2000.